# How to get values inside of brackets according to BODMAS rule

Tags: regex, parsing, preg-match

I tried and stuck to this formula which only only work on 1 pair of brackets:

```
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $text, $match);
print $match[1];
```

What I want to do is parse the text after the last open parenthesis before the first close parenthesis.

For example, I have equation like this:

> 1+(2+(3+(5-6)))+(7-8)

The text that would be parsed is "5-6".

Comment: Use `'~\(([^()]*)\)~'`

Comment: It works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match `(` > anything except `(` or `)` > `)`

```
$text = '1+(2+(3+(5-6)))+(7-8)';
preg_match('/\(([^\(\)]+)\)/', $text, $match);
var_dump($match);
```